# php directives in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, php-ini, php

I have attempted to make a few changes to php via .htaccess, yet none have yielded any results.  For example:

`php_value memory_limit 256M` within  will not activate.

Attempting to set `SetEnv PHPRC /home/username/public_html/php.ini` or any similar incantation, such as `SetEnv PHPRC /home/username/some_path`, will not work yield any difference in phpinfo.  I DO see that `_SERVER["PHPRC"]` is indeed set, but no values are overwritten such as that noted above.

My phpinfo is as follows:
https://gist.github.com/ylluminate/08efd9a2844723631214

I'm wondering if I'm missing an apache module that's not allowing this to work as expected for a custom php.ini or phprc.  Further This is an Apache 2.4.4 installation on a VPS over which I have 100% control (Linode) and using WHM + cPanel.

Comment: This depends on the apache configurations, if you're on a shared hosting you're probably out of luck as you won't be able to use ini_set or php.ini nor the htaccess to change values related to php configurations, Your best option is asking your host to change this for your vhost.

Comment: If you are using CGI/FastCGI, why not try `.user.ini` for overriding settings?

Comment: @ahmad no, I'm on a VPS with 100% control and using WHM / cPanel.

Comment: @mario that's interesting. I guess it's been a while since I've done a lot with php configuration as I did not see that this style was added since 5.3. So as I understand it you can just create a .user.ini file within the hierarchical parent folder that you want the settings to be active in, correct?

Comment: @mario add that as an answer please, your suggestion worked perfectly.

Comment: @mario - elegant solution, could you post it as an answer? helps us sifting through the unanswered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PHP 5.3 you can use `.user.ini` files, given that PHP is setup to run via the CGI/FastCGI SAPI.
http://php.net/configuration.file.per-user

It's a simple extension of the main `php.ini` and allows specifying options equivalently:

```
memory_limit = 256M
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
```

Usually you can place one of these in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. But every directory may contain one, so options may vary per script/folder. It's meant as full alternative to Apaches/mod_php `.htaccess` setting directives.